# How do I align a multi-layered cartoon character in After Effects?

Tags: after-effects

I selected all the layers of the character and opened the align panel and pressed vertical and horizontal alignment but the eyes, shadows and all the inner features of the character get aligned too into the center

How can I do it?

Comment: how did you create the character images?

Comment: Also, a screenshot might give us a better idea of what's happening